# What does "trace" mean in "pdb.set_trace()"?

Tags: python

I use `pdb.set_trace()` in a script to set a breakpoint.

But I can't figure out why the function is called `set_trace`.

It seem that `trace` often appears in discussion of executing or debugging a program. 
What does `trace` mean in the executing or debugging a program?

Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_(software)

Answer (score 3):

The Python debugger is implemented on top of the `sys.settrace` function.  This is a way to register a Python function that will be invoked for every line of code executed.  As the Python interpreter executes your code, it will call the trace function for each line it encounters.  The trace function can do whatever it likes.

The debugger has a trace function that it uses to track the execution of your code.  It examines the current stack frame to see if you've gotten to a breakpoint, for example.  `pdb.set_trace` means, "set the pdb trace function as the trace function with sys.settrace."

It's not a good name, because it describes how the function is implemented, rather than what it does for the user.

Comment: THanks. WHat does "sys.settrace" do? What do you mean by " register a Python function that will be invoked for every line of code executed"?

Comment: I've added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

As with many computer terms, it's a metaphor for something in the real world. Here are relevant [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trace) definitions of trace

- a mark or line left by something that has passed
- a path, trail, or road made by the passage of animals, people, or vehicles

Tracking the progress through a computer program is analogous to following the path of something that has passed.

Usually when we refer to tracing in general, it's a debugging application that shows all the activities of a program. Setting a breakpoint is considered a subset of this.

Comment: Thanks. Then why does `pdb.set_trace()` seem only set a breakpoint?

Comment: It's just what some programmer decided to call it.

Comment: it's not like everyone carefully decides on the perfect name for everything they do.